# How to access first letter of a word in a string which is inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array which consists of one cell which holds a string.

```
var myArray = ["hopefully i will get an answer to this problem"]
```

Trying to loop through the array itself isn't bearing any fruit as i am not used to working with only one cell.

```
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(myArray[i]);
} //returns the whole string "hopefully i will get an answer to this problem"
//this would allow me to loop through many cells in one array but here i only have one cell in one aray
```

Now i would like to do something with the first letter of each word.

But as i said above, the typical array iteration i am used to doing is often working with many cells not a single cell.

**My Question then is as follows:**

Given this array with a single cell

`var myArray = ["hopefully i will get an answer to this problem"]`

What is the best way to get hold of the first letter of each word to do something to it.

**NOTE:**

- If it helps you to form an answer I actually need to capitalize the first letter of every word

Comment: What happens when `i` is 0? That is, what is the value of `i - 1`?

Comment: *"I am able to access every letter in this array using [...] `myArray[i]`"* – Uhm, no. `myArray[0]` accesses the entire string which is in the first index of the array. You're not looping over the string letter by letter, you're looping over the array which contains exactly one string, hence the loop is only executed once.

Comment: @deceze you are correct, cleaning up question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array with 1 element in it. You first loop makes only one iteration and outputs this first element.
I believe what you want to do is the following:

```
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
  if(myArray[0][i] === " "){
    //do some code with myArray[i]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to point out here:

#### 1) You don't need the array to loop over a string

JS strings act as an array of characters on their own, so you can indeed loop over them. In your example however, you're looping over the outer array, which holds only one element, so its `length` is 1. This means that the line

```
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
```

combined with the fact that you decrement `i` by 1 later here

```
console.log(myArray[i-1])
```

means that your function loops from `-1` (i-1) and ends when it reaches `0` (i<1). As `myArray[-1]` is `undefined`, that's where your result comes from.
If you remove the outer array, your approach would work with just the string.

#### 2) A loop isn't always the best for string manipulation

Then again, there are better ways to achieve what you're trying to do. JS has built-in functions for [splitting a string into an array of words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [joining an array of strings into a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). Combine that with your approach to loop over single words or [charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) to find individual characters by their index and you can make your code a lot more straightforward.

Also, take a look at the [built-in methods and properties of Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) that can make your life easier, such as `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

there are may more than one spaces in the empty item of array. So before match you can clear all of spaces like this

```
for(var i=1; i<myArray.length; i++) {
  if(myArray[i-1].toString().replace(/\s/g,'') === ''){
    //do some code with myArray[i]
  }
}
```

or

```
for(var i=1; i<myArray.length; i++) {
  if(!myArray[i-1].toString().replace(/\s/g,'')){
    //do some code with myArray[i]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

myArray.length = 1 so don't use array the for can't traversal this , use string

Comment: if you must use that  u can use myArray[0].length